# Some trouble in loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Hi there,
I'm a newbie in java and I have a problem with this code. I'm thinking if it is a problem in loop or something..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int z = 0;
        String input;
        int[] ABArray = new int[2];

        while (z == 0) {
            System.out.println("Input X to terminate.");
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            input = scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                char AB = input.charAt(i);

                ABArray[AB - 'a']++;
            }

            if (ABArray[0] == 0 || ABArray[1] == 0) {
                System.out.println("Not Equal");
                System.out.println("");

            } else if (ABArray[0] == ABArray[1]) {
                System.out.println("Equal");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (ABArray[0] != ABArray[1]) {
                System.out.println("Not Equal");
                if (ABArray[0] > ABArray[1]) {
                    System.out.println("The number of A is greater than B.");
                } else if (ABArray[0] < ABArray[1]) {
                    System.out.println("The number of B is greater than A.");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException X) { }  //Terminates the program

}
```

**The problem is this**
**I/O**

```
Input:                      
ABABAB

Output:                              
Equal

Input:                          
AABBB

Output:                            
Not Equal
The number of B is greater than A.

Input:                                 
AABB    //It is equal.

Output:                       
Not Equal  //It says not.
The number of B is greater than A.
```

As you see, the problem is when I input equal A and B at the first, it says equal, when I input not equal A and B but at the third when I input equal A and B it says not equal.

**Problem solved.
Thanks for the help.**

Comment: What is the purpose of your program?

Comment: @ADTC To check if the number of A's and B's are equal or not.

Comment: And how do you do that? (The algorithm) *Please expand your question with this information*

Comment: If the problem was solved, please accept one of the given answers or describe how you solved the problem by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set all the values in `ABArray` to zero every time you start to work inside the `while` loop. Right now on the third time you start the `while` loop (with `AABB` input) you still keep the values which were left from the previous run of the loop - `5` in the 0-indexed element of an array and `6` in the 1-indexed element of an array, thus the program gives you the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

How about you simply read in the input into a string, then loop through it, counting the number of occurrences of each character you are interested in (here 'a' and 'b'), checking whether their counts are equal? So this works for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input;

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Input X to terminate.");
                System.out.print("Input: ");
                input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                if (input.equals("X")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    int countA = 0;
                    int countB = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                        if (input.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                            countA++;
                        } else if (input.charAt(i) == 'b') {
                            countB++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (countA == countB) {
                        System.out.println("Equal!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Not equal!");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) // Terminates the program
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    try
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int z=0;
        String input;
        int[] ABArray = null;

        while(z==0)
        {
            ABArray = new int[2];
            System.out.println("Input X to terminate.");
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            input=scn.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) 
            {
                char AB=input.charAt(i);

                ABArray[AB-'a']++;

            }

            if(ABArray[0]==0||ABArray[1]==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Not Equal");
                System.out.println("");

            }
            else if(ABArray[0]==ABArray[1])
            {
                System.out.println("Equal");
                System.out.println("");
            }
            else if(ABArray[0]!=ABArray[1])
            {
                System.out.println("Not Equal");
                if(ABArray[0]>ABArray[1])
                {
                    System.out.println("The number of A is greater than B.");
                }
                else if(ABArray[0]<ABArray[1])
                {
                    System.out.println("The number of B is greater than A.");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException X) //Terminates the program
    {
      X.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```